# Projeto do Visual Studio perdendo referências via git

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github, referência

Ao clonar um projeto, o mesmo está vindo com algumas referências em branco, tendo que adicionar manualmente. Este problema só ocorre com projetos clonados, caso baixe o projeto como zip pelo github, ele funciona normalmente.

Já tentei utilizar o source tree e o próprio visual studio 2015 para fazer o download.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução seria deixar que o `VS` corrija automaticamente os pacotes com problema, para isso, habilite a opção `Restore Nuget Packages`, botão direito sobre o projeto, depois é só recompilar o projeto.

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ao selecionar está opção, ele retorna está mensagem:

Comment: All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.

Comment: Fez `clean` depois `rebuid`?

Comment: sim, aparentemente os packages estão ok, o problema é o path que está ficando em branco

Comment: Fiz um teste, ao copiar a pasta packages do projeto que está funcionando e colocar no projeto baixado com o git, o mesmo funcionou. A dúvida que fica é, por que quando o projeto é baixado inteiro com git ele está perdendo este caminho...